# How can I code an iOS app while on my iPhone without a pc

Tags: html, ios, iphone, iphone-5

Is it possible for me to develop and iOS app on my phone? I wanna either code an app off my iPhone 5 or just make my website into an app. Is there somewhere I can go to do this or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make an app from your iPhone 5. You can only create iPhone apps with a native programming language using Xcode. But, you can convert your website to an app using an application like PhoneGap, or you could use a JavaScript library like Electron.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can only programming on Xcode. And if you want to make your website into an app, you can use WKWebView. You can build a wkwebview with a url, then your app would just like a browser. And you can what you want in the  website.